# Using shrinkwrap doesn't wrap the object correctly

Tags: shrinkwrap

I'm trying to add my logo design to a shoulderpad of a miniature.

- I imported a .svg file (my logo) and a existing .stl of the shoulderpad.
- I transferred the .svg logo to a mesh object.
- I added a lattice to the logo and made it flat and the size of the shoulderpad.
- I added a shrinkwrap to the lattice and linked it to the shoulderpad.

[image: This is my result] This is my result, logo show's on the inside of the shoulderpad and isn't realy wrapped around the curved outerparts :(
What am I missing? Do I need to add different settings to the shrinkwrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your logo has only one face, it can't bend/shrinkwrap on a curved surface. Add a subdivision modifier to the logo so it creates more geometry, allowing it to bend. I would also try adding the shrinkwrap to the logo instead of the lattice.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and see what the results are.

Comment: Yes, it's showing in the curved way now. I deleted the lattice and added the Shripwrap on the Logo. The logo is very meshy, or in real words, I guess I need to clean it somehow because it's get very bumpy now when wraped on the Shoulderpad. But that's a different issue.

Also I see the shrinkwrap isn't a square shape anymore but the top is smaller than the bottom. How does this happen or can be avoided? Because the logo now looks a bit squeezed on the top side.

Comment: Glad it worked, or at least getting closer. Distorsions can happen because of Wrap Method inside the modifier. Switch from Nearest surface point to Project. Then on Axis choose the one that applies here (I think Y in this case), and check Negative (or Positive, depending on which way is the logo facing), also switch Face Cull from off to the others, see which works. It shoud now wrap without distorting.

Comment: For the bumpiness, try adding the subdivision (put above shrinkwrap in the modifier list, maybe needs more geometry. If it doesn't work, I would try to clean it, leaving only the outer line, and add subdiv after. Hope it works.